# Need to display a span inside text with set width and height

Tags: html, css

I have emoticons in a css sprite image that I want to display within text, so I have spans inserted with background definitions but as these spans are inline elements I can not define the width and height.

The only thing I could think of is make them block elements and float left, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. What do you think is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use the css property and value `display: inline-block`

Comment: and `line-height` or negative margins to make things look tidy.

Comment: Thanks, is inline-block supported by all modern browsers?

Comment: for compatibly have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html
only ie 5.5 has a problem with inline-block on span elements

Comment: @DavidW - yes, `inline-block` has good support. IE6 and IE7 have bugs with their support, but they do support it. All other browsers in use today are fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that `display: inline-block` is supported enough to rely on. Obviously I am talking about <=IE7, and possibly other mobile devices. Which unfortunately are still in use. However there comes a point when one stops supporting IE.

I would try using a div floated, with background attributes set.  Failing that a single image.

Comment: you are right, that <=IE7 are buggy, but I had never a problem with a span that uses inline-box and height equals the line-height of the surrounding box (also tested on ie 6).